# MS SQL seems to cache select result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently creating a selection query and observed a strange behaviour. Perhaps someone can explain this.

Please check out the following query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT count(*) from [DummyData].[dbo].[Users]) as numberOfEntriesInDummy,
  (ABS(checksum(Name) % (SELECT count(*) from [DummyData].[dbo].[Users])) + 1) as randomId, 
  (Select [Name] FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users] WHERE Id = (ABS(checksum(Name) % (SELECT count(*)     from [DummyData].[dbo].[Users])) + 1)) as randName
FROM [invoiceR-Test].[dbo].[AbpUsers]
```

This query gives me this result:

```
numberOfEntriesInDummy  randomId    randName
14                      9           Leano                                             
14                      9           Leano                                             
14                      3           Leano                                             
14                      5           Leano                                             
14                      13          Leano                                             
14                      11          Leano
```

What I do not understand is why gives the "randName" column always the same result? "Leano" is only once in the [DummyData].[dbo].[Users]-Table and has the ID 7. Actually I would expect that the last column has changing names in it.

The second column shows clearly that the randomId is actually changing form row to row - but the queried result in the last column is always the same. For me it looks like the query result to the [DummyData].[dbo].[Users]-Table is somehow cached...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an error because you have not qualified your column references.  The relevant part of your query is:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT [Name]
        FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users]
        WHERE Id = (ABS(checksum(Name) %
                    (SELECT count(*) FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users])) + 1)) as randName
       )
FROM [invoiceR-Test].[dbo].[AbpUsers];
```

My guess is that you intend:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT u.[Name]
        FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users] u
        WHERE u.Id = (ABS(checksum(u.Name) %
                    (SELECT count(*) FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users])) + 1)) as randName
       )
FROM [invoiceR-Test].[dbo].[AbpUsers] au;
```

However, `users` doesn't have a `name` column, so this is interpreted as:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT au.[Name]
        FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users] u
        WHERE u.Id = (ABS(checksum(au.Name) %
                    (SELECT count(*) FROM [DummyData].[dbo].[Users])) + 1)) as randName
       )
FROM [invoiceR-Test].[dbo].[AbpUsers] au;
```

The moral is to always qualify ALL column references in a query.